# Uniqueness property of self-adjoint operators

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am currently working through a proof for the spectral theorem for bounded self-adjoint operators. At one point, the following theorem is used without proof:

Let $A, B$ be two self-adjoint operators on the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ with $\mathcal{D}(A) = \mathcal{D}(B)$. If $(Af,f) = (Bf,f)$ for all $f \in \mathcal{D}(A)$, it follows that $A = B$.

I only know a proof for the corresponding statement with $(Af,g) = (Bf,g)$ for general (i.e., not necessarily self-adjoint) operators $A,B$. Therefore I wanted to ask if the statement given above is actually true and if so, how it can be proven?

Comment: You can use the polarisation identity, which holds for $A$ symmetric and $f,g$ in the domain of $A$:

$$\langle Af,g\rangle = \frac14\sum_{k=1}^4i^{-k}\langle A (f+i^kg),f+i^kg\rangle$$

Comment: Thank you, I see how the statement in question would follow from this formula. Do you know a reference for it where I can read up additional details?

Comment: You can expand the expression on the right and everything should cancel in the right way to give you the expression on the left (provided I made no mistakes in writing the formula). You can read a bit more about it in this wiki link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity